# mysql in Xampp Not work

Tags: mysql, xampp

after update kernel to 4.0.3 in ubuntu phpmadmin in xampp not work

i try this

```
 sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.8-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.

and

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

Stopping XAMPP for Linux 5.6.8-0...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...not running.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...not running.

Im try this

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.

and

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
```

sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/var/mysql -R
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart

finally  I remove xampp and re install but the MySQL is not work

Comment: when i go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/                                           MySQL said: Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is Stop Apache and Mysql first

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

Then Start your Xampp

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

or

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

This should Work